# Variable 'a' implicitly has an 'any[]' type

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to run `npm start` for my angular2 project

but get this error:

```
  push_quick git:(master) npm start

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start /Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/SupporTool/src/main/webapp/html/push_quick
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"

app/shared/stringUtils.service.ts(8,9): error TS7005: Variable 'a' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.3.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
```

for this method:

```
@Injectable()
export class StringUtilsService {

  mapToFormParamsString( dict : any) : string{
    var a:any[] = []
    for (var key in dict) {
      if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        a.push(key+"="+dict[key]);
      }
    }
    return a.join("&");
  }
}
```

how can i fix this?

changing `var a = string[]`  or `var a = any[]`

didn't help. same compilation error.

btw, I didn't have thi error when compiling with `ng start` or in intellij

Is `ng start` calling `mpn start` or visa versa ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Probably, in the strinUtils.service.ts. A member or a variable of the componenet has not explicit type. A quick way to fix, since you are not providing the service code, may be

```
var a:string[] = []
```

The error showed happens on the linting validations, sometimes if the linter is no passing it breaks the compile runtime.

Comment: thanks! btw, I didn't have thi error when compiling with ng start or in intellij
how come?
Is ng start calling mpn start or visa versa ?