# Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

In testing my UserRouter, I am using a json file

**data.json**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Luke Cage",
    "aliases": ["Carl Lucas", "Power Man", "Mr. Bulletproof", "Hero for Hire"],
    "occupation": "bartender",
    "gender": "male",
    "height": {
      "ft": 6,
      "in": 3
    },
    "hair": "bald",
    "eyes": "brown",
    "powers": [
      "strength",
      "durability",
      "healing"
    ]
  },
  {
  ...
  }
]
```

Building my app, I get the following TS error

```
ERROR in ...../UserRouter.ts
(30,27): error TS7006: Parameter 'user' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

**UserRouter.ts**

```
import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
const Users = require('../data');

export class UserRouter {
  router: Router;

  constructor() {
  ...
  }

  /**
   * GET one User by id
   */
  public getOne(req: Request, res: Response, _next: NextFunction) {
    let query = parseInt(req.params.id);
 /*[30]->*/let user = Users.find(user => user.id === query);
    if (user) {
      res.status(200)
        .send({
          message: 'Success',
          status: res.status,
          user
        });
    }
    else {
      res.status(404)
        .send({
          message: 'No User found with the given id.',
          status: res.status
        });
    }
  }


}

const userRouter = new UserRouter().router;
export default userRouter;
```

Comment: Can you show us your `tsconfig`? By the look of it you have `noImplicitAny` enabled and that is what causing the error.

Comment: All these comments and answers suggesting that you disable `strict` or `noImplicitAny` are terrible. You might as well use JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you both.  I shall use these settings temporarily!

Answer (score 611, accepted):

You are using the `--noImplicitAny` and TypeScript doesn't know about the type of the `Users` object. In this case, you need to explicitly define the `user` type.

Change this line:

```
let user = Users.find(user => user.id === query);
```

to this:

```
let user = Users.find((user: any) => user.id === query); 
// use "any" or some other interface to type this argument
```

Or define the type of your `Users` object:

```
//...
interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    aliases: string[];
    occupation: string;
    gender: string;
    height: {ft: number; in: number;}
    hair: string;
    eyes: string;
    powers: string[]
}
//...
const Users = <User[]>require('../data');
//...
```

Comment: In your tsconfig.json add this   "noImplicitAny": false to "compilerOptions":{} it will work

Comment: @naval-kishor-jha , but noImplicitAny is a good option , we have to find a solution with noImplicitAny as true , is that a Typescript issue ?

Comment: Sometimes,  I encounter this problem then I quickly search on StackOverflow, I see my vote to you, every time I'm mad at myself for this problem :) I hope so, I will never see this page

Comment: Disabling `noImplicitAny` without understanding the implications of doing so is a bad decision and it should not be recommended without additional explanation. It should only be disabled if you're migrating from a type-loose codebase and as a short-term measure. Disabling it will reduce compiler errors, but some of those are hinting at actual bugs in your code; those bugs are still present but now invisible.

Consider that `noImplicitAny: true` doesn't mean you can't use `any`. It means you have to do it with consideration. It only takes a few moments to type `: any`.

Comment: If you change your import to an `import` instead of `require`, Typescript will infer the type of the JSON object as if you defined it inline. You won't have an implicit `any`, and you won't have to define any special interfaces that you blindly hope will match the shape of the JSON object. It's very good. 
It's possible this was a more recent addition to Typescript, I don't know when it started doing this.

Answer (score 205):

In your `tsconfig.json` file set the parameter `"noImplicitAny": false` under `compilerOptions` to get rid of this error.

Comment: Careful. This workaround silences the error and only fixes the symptom; it doesn't fix the root cause.

Comment: @jbmusso is right. Try to use the strict mode instead of shutting it down. This way you won't find errors at runtime

Answer (score 49):

Make these changes in your `compilerOptions` section of `tsconfig.json` file this worked for me

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

no need to set

```
"strict":false
```

And please wait 1 or two minutes compilation is very slow some pcs

Comment: this solution turns off a major benefit of TypeScript, which is type checking. In my opinion this solution should be avoided.

Comment: Applying this solution means death of typescript. Avoid it.

Comment: to use some of typescript(better than nothing) instead of going full 100% typescript, this flag is very useful and much less noisy to me.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer of [@st_ahmed's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52710206/327074) 3 years after...

Answer (score 20):

I found this issue in Angular to arguments of function.

Before my code giving error

> Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type

Here Is code

```
changeInpValue(event)
{
    this.inp = event.target.value;
}
```

Here is the change, after the argument write `: any` and the error is solved

```
changeInpValue(event : any)
{
    this.inp = event.target.value;
}
```

Working fine for me.

Answer (score 15):

if you get an error as **Parameter 'element' implicitly has an 'any' type.Vetur(7006)**
in  **vueJs**

> with the error:

```
 exportColumns.forEach(element=> {
      if (element.command !== undefined) {
        let d = element.command.findIndex(x => x.name === "destroy");
```

you can fixed it by defining thoes variables as any as follow.

> corrected code:

```
exportColumns.forEach((element: any) => {
      if (element.command !== undefined) {
        let d = element.command.findIndex((x: any) => x.name === "destroy");
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thanks.  The 'element' of the ForEach needed surrounding in parenthesis before it could have a type assigned to it.  i.e. .forEach((element: object)...

Answer (score 6):

#### Minimal error reproduction

```
export const users = require('../data'); // presumes @types/node are installed
const foundUser = users.find(user => user.id === 42); 
// error: Parameter 'user' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
```

#### Recommended solution: `--resolveJsonModule`

The simplest way for your case is to use [`--resolveJsonModule`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) compiler option:

```
import users from "./data.json" // `import` instead of `require`
const foundUser = users.find(user => user.id === 42); // user is strongly typed, no `any`!
```

---

There are some alternatives for other cases than static JSON import.

#### Option 1: Explicit user type (simple, no checks)

```
type User = { id: number; name: string /* and others */ }
const foundUser = users.find((user: User) => user.id === 42)
```

#### Option 2: Type guards (middleground)

[Type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) are a good middleground between simplicity and strong types:

```
function isUserArray(maybeUserArr: any): maybeUserArr is Array<User> {
  return Array.isArray(maybeUserArr) && maybeUserArr.every(isUser)
}

function isUser(user: any): user is User {
  return "id" in user && "name" in user
}

if (isUserArray(users)) {
  const foundUser = users.find((user) => user.id === 42)
}
```

You can even switch to [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) (TS 3.7+) to get rid of `if` and throw an error instead.

```
function assertIsUserArray(maybeUserArr: any): asserts maybeUserArr is Array<User> {
  if(!isUserArray(maybeUserArr)) throw Error("wrong json type")
}

assertIsUserArray(users)
const foundUser = users.find((user) => user.id === 42) // works
```

#### Option 3: Runtime type system library (sophisticated)

A runtime type check library like [`io-ts`](http://io-ts) or [`ts-runtime`](https://github.com/fabiandev/ts-runtime) can be integrated for more complex cases.

---

#### ***Not*** recommended solutions

[`noImplicitAny: false`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) undermines many useful checks of the type system:

```
function add(s1, s2) { // s1,s2 implicitely get `any` type
  return s1 * s2 // `any` type allows string multiplication and all sorts of types :(
}
add("foo", 42)
```

Also better provide an explicit `User` type for `user`. This will avoid propagating `any` to inner layer types. Instead typing and validating is kept in the JSON processing code of the outer API layer.

Answer (score 4):

go to tsconfig.json and comment the line the //strict:true   this worked for me

Answer (score 4):

My case:

```
export default function ({user, path}) {
    return (
        //...
    )
}
```

I changed to

```
export default function ({user, path} : {
    user: string
    path: string
}) {
    return (
        //...
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I encounted this error and found that it was because the "strict" parameter was set to true in the tsconfig.json file. Just set it "false" (obviously). In my case I had generated the tsconfig file from the cmd prompt and simply missed the "strict" parameter, which was located further down in the file.

Comment: Setting strict mode to false is very bad. You won't get errors on compile time anymore but you will get them at runtime, which you don't want. I highly recommend setting the strict mode to `true`

Answer (score 1):

try to declare the type of user.
Such as

```
let user:Object = {sample object}
```

Follow this methid.
As

```
let var:type = val
```

Answer (score 1):

Or add the below on top of the code that has the error

```
// @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Parameter 'post' implicitly has an 'any' type** in Angularcli
Perhaps on project creation you've enabled Angular's strict mode in your app?
Max recommends to disable strict mode
If you've enabled **strict mode**, please disable it for this course by setting the strict property in tsconfig.json to **false**

Answer (score -4):

Just add `"checkJs": false` into `jsconfig.json` file