# Parameter 'm' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, angular5

I am getting an error while running my project.

This is the code :

```js
private populateModels() {
    var selectedMake = this.makes.find(m => m.id == this.vehicle.makeId);
    this.models = selectedMake ? selectedMake.models : [];
}
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/app/components/vehicle-form/vehicle-form.component.ts:82:40
          TS7006: Parameter 'm' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add a type to your `m` variable this way:

```
private populateModels() {
    var selectedMake = this.makes.find( (m: any) => {
        m.id == this.vehicle.makeId);
    });

    this.models = selectedMake ? selectedMake.models : [];
}
```

So you have to add `m: any` or `m: vehicle` depending on the type you are using for your model. and this error will disapear.