# Firebase Cloud Messaging - getMessaging is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to send a message from a node.js  app in firebase to an android device using code snippets from the firebase website.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple

Keep getting `getMessaging is not a function.`

My call is  `await admin.messaging().getMessaging().send(...)`

Can't find what is wrong.

Answer (score 13):

The `getMessaging()` function that you are referring to is a top level function that can be imported from `firebase-admin/messaging` SDK as shown below:

```
import { getMessaging } from "firebase-admin/messaging";
```

This is equivalent of `admin.messaging()` and both return an instance of [Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging) class.

If you are following Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) to send messages, the code should be:

```
import { getMessaging } from "firebase-admin/messaging"; // not just "firebase-admin"

const messaging = getMessaging();

await messaging.send(...)
```

---

The Admin SDK is not fully modular yet like the the client SDK so rest of the syntax remains same. Also checkout [What is the difference between admin.firestore, admin.firestore() and getFirestore()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72695555/what-is-the-difference-between-admin-firestore-admin-firestore-and-getfiresto)

Answer (score 3):

You're using `firebase-admin` sdk which does have different syntax. For your use-case, you should instead use:

```
await admin.messaging().send(...);
```

---

For more information, checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging#getmessaging).