# Avoiding implicit any warnings for uninteresting parameters?

Tags: typescript

When defining a callback to pass to an existing API, often some parameters of the callback end up not being used. In TypeScript [such parameters can be marked](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9458) by starting their names with an underscore.

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        user: (__, {id}: {id: number}): Promise<User[]> => {
            return findUser(id);
    }
}
```

However, in the example above, this still leads to a TypeScript warning: `[ts] Parameter '__' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage. [7044]`

Since I'm not using the `__` parameter, it would be a waste of time and space to declare its type.

I'm aware that I could disable the [`--noImplicitAny`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type) TypeScript option. However, I prefer to have this warning in the cases where it makes sense. Only in this case, where I'm not interested in the type of the parameter as it's not used, would I prefer not to get the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the type if only `__:any` if it can't be inferred from context.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the right thing to want.
When you create an @ts-ignore comment, you ignore any error reporting that occurs on the next line.

```
@ts-ignore
```