# error TS7006: Parameter '_' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have class that implements ControlValueAccessor (from '@angular/forms'):

```
export abstract class xxx implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private _value: any = '';
    private onChange = (_) => {};

    get value(): any {
      return this._value;
    }

    set value(v: any) {
      if (v !== this._value) {
        this._value = v;
        this.onChange(v);
      }
    }
....
...
```

This gives me a build error on line:
private onChange = (_) => {};

and says:
 error TS7006: Parameter '_' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: if you want to avoid the error set 'Strict':false in tsconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43070857/5621827)  changing

```
private onChange = (_) => {};
```

to

```
private onChange = (_:any) => {};
```

should work

Comment: this doesn't work if you have this rule set (which I think is quite common): `"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error"`, I wonder if there's a way to tell TS and ESLint to ignore any `_` prefixed params?