# function name type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I use 'strict' mode in `TypeScript`

I have a button that triggers a dynamic function;

```
 <button
    type="button"
    (click)="handleFunctionCall(action)" // action is dynamic function name of type string
 ></button>
```

here is the function

```
// handler function to replace function name dynamically
handleFunctionCall(functionName) {
    this[functionName]()
}
```

how to make the following error disappear ?

`Parameter 'functionName' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

**Edit:**

in case of adding `string` type like so

```
// handler function to replace function name dynamically
handleFunctionCall(functionName: string) { // string was added
    this[functionName]()
}
```

I get a different error

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MenuComponent'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MenuComponent'`

Comment: `handleFunctionCall(functionName)` -> `handleFunctionCall(functionName: any)` to make it explicit. Although, it's better if you don't allow just anything, `handleFunctionCall(functionName: string)` is a start but you can also limit it to just the available functions. See [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43064221)

Comment: I don't want to use `any` and when I do this `handleFunctionCall(functionName: string)` I get the following error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type` of my component name.

Comment: `keyof YourClass`? But not all of the props are methods are callable without any arguments, most notably `handleFunctionCall` itself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe as an addendum, it's possible to just enumerate the callable properties, so `handleFunctionCall(functionName: "foo" | "bar" | "baz")`

Comment: @VLAZ you can do "callable props" more easily, see e.g. [how Jasmine does it](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d063d0175b3eb59a7a4cc5e64992f8a220d9a910/types/jasmine/index.d.ts#L292-L295), still have the arity problem.