# Object literal's property 'bedRooms' implicitly has an 'any' type. Error TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am new to typeScript. I have declared a type anotation object in my react app.

```
type DefaultHomeValueProps = {
    value?: number
    asOf?: Date
    HomeType: string
    bedRooms: number | null | undefined
    baths : number | null | undefined
    squareFeet : number
    lastSold : Date 
}
```

When I give bedRooms a value of null or Undefined, it shows me an error:

`(property) bedRooms: null Object literal's property 'bedRooms' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: could you show it in Typescript playground? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43070857/495157 - perhaps this helps.. (In your tsconfig.json add this "noImplicitAny": false to "compilerOptions":{} )