# Not all code paths return a value in Typescript and Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a small project and I am basically dealing with registration and authentication using `Express` and `Angular 9`.
Everything was going well when I got the error `Not all code paths return a value` in the file **register.component.ts** and was not able to understand what is missing in that typescript file.

**validate.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ValidateService {

  constructor() { }

  validateRegister(user) {
    if(user.name == undefined || user.email == undefined || user.password == undefined) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  validateEmail(email) {
    // operations ...
  }
}
```

**register.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidateService } from '../../services/validate.service';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  name!: String;
  username!: String;
  email!: String;
  password!: String;

  constructor(private validateService: ValidateService, private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onRegisterSubmit() {
    const user = {
      name: this.name,
      username: this.username,
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }

    // Required fields
    if(!this.validateService.validateRegister(user)) {
      this.flashMessage.show('Please fill in all fields', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
      return false;
    }

    // Required fields
    if(!this.validateService.validateEmail(user.email)) {
      this.flashMessage.show('Please fill in all fields', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
      return false;
    } else console.log('Correct');
  }
}
```

Finally on the **register.components.html** I am passing the `onRegisterSubmit()`:

```
<h2 class="page-header">Register</h2>
 <form (submit)="onRegisterSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" class="form-control">
  </div>
 </form>
```

The problem seems to lie on the **register.component.ts** file as something seems to be missing.
Initially I thought I could be a non correct initialization problem but I could not find anything. I also went thought [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type) which was useful to evaluate an additional option. However that didn't solve the problem. I appreciate anyone how could possibly point me to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pointing out that onRegisterSubmit can make it to the end without hitting a `return` statement. Since this may indicate a bug, it gives you an error. To fix it, change this:

```
} else console.log('Correct');
```

To this:

```
} else {
  console.log('Correct');
  return true;
}
```

I'm just guessing that `true` is what you want to return, since you return `false` in the other cases. If you deliberately wanted to return `undefined`, do this:

```
} else {
  console.log('Correct');
  return undefined;
}
```

Or this:

```
} else {
  console.log('Correct');
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was it! I see what was happening now!