# (node:15976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when trying to connect to mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, typescript

The code to connect to mongodb and why do I get an error on async.

[image]

And when I execute `npm run start` I get the following error

[image]

Please help ! Thank you.

Comment: It is a good practice to code snippets as text and not as image. This keeps it searchable, and other users can copy and try reproduce.

Comment: Add a try catch inside your function, the message will be explicit

Comment: You can try-catch to surrounding the code that is trying to connect the database to avoid this error. But it seems like your code is not able to access the database... so a network or configuration bug, less likely a code related issue.

Answer (score 0):

use try catch to handle and avoid this warning of promise rejection
A way to resolve this is .

```js
mongoose
  .connect(
    db,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(function(){ 
    console.log('MongoDB Connected')
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

To do this without callback use async await this way.

```
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${server}/${database}`, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true
        });
        console.log('MongoDB connected!!');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Failed to connect to MongoDB', err);
    }
```

Comment: I get an error : Parameter 'err' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type