# parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type. TS(7006)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm still fairly new to JavaScript and TypeScript. I'm trying to write a basic filter that removes restaurants (from ./restaurants)based on the function restaurantFilt. I'm not sure why my 'i' variable is getting this error message on VSCode, could someone explain what it means / how to fix it please?

Thank you!

```
//Write application that we put in time, distance, price and delivery time to recommend restaurant

import restaurants from './restaurants'; //imported the restaurants from file.

let currentHour = 15;
let willingToWait = 40; //minutes
let price = '$'; 
let distance = 4; //miles

//Write function that will be used inside restaurant.filter
let priceBracket = price.length;

let restaurantFilt = (i) => { 
    if (distance > Number(i.distance)) { //if distance user inputs is greater than i's distance return false.
        return false;
    }
    if (i.waitTime > willingToWait) { //User Max wait time > Restaurant Max => remove item
        return false;
    }
    if (priceBracket != i.priceBracket) { //if users price bracket is not equal to i's price bracket, remove item
        return false;
    }
    if (currentHour < i.openHour || currentHour > i.closeHour) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true; //returns a value which equals true
    }
}

let postRestFilt = restaurants.filter(restaurantFilt);

console.log(postRestFilt);
```

Here is the file being used that's being imported for restaurants!

```
export default [
    {
      name: 'Silver Rice Sushi ',
      priceBracket: '1',
      waitTime: 40,
      openHour: '12',
      closeHour: '23',
      distance: '5',
    },
    {
      name: 'Nikko\'s Rotisserie Chicken ',
      priceBracket: '2',
      waitTime: 20,
      openHour: '12',
      closeHour: '21',
      distance: '8',
    },
    {
      name: 'Aita Trattoria ',
      priceBracket: '3',
      waitTime: 60,
      openHour: '18',
      closeHour: '22',
      distance: '1',
    },
    {
      name: 'Lula Bagel ',
      priceBracket: '1',
      waitTime: 20,
      openHour: '0',
      closeHour: '12',
      distance: '2',
    },
    {
      name: 'Golden Chopstick ',
      priceBracket: '2',
      waitTime: 20,
      openHour: '15',
      closeHour: '23',
      distance: '12',
    },
  ];
```

So we're importing an array that has objects inside!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the type that `i` is in this line:

```
let restaurantFilt = (i) => {
```

This would be whatever type `restaurants` is (exported from the `restaurants` file), for example:

```
let restaurantFilt = (i: Restaurant) => {
```

Your code snippet doesn't give us enough information to say what exactly the type should be, but this is what's missing.

Edit:

Based on your edit, there's a few things you can do.

First, you're implicitly typing *everything*, which isn't typically how you'd write typescript. It works a lot of the time (i.e., `let currentHour = 15` works because it knows that `15` is numeric) and similarly this works:

```
export default [
  {
    name: 'Silver Rice Sushi ',
    priceBracket: '1',
    waitTime: 40,
    openHour: '12',
    closeHour: '23',
    distance: '5',
  },
  ...
]
```

because typescript can determine that this is an array of objects matching the shape:

```
name: string,
priceBracket: string,
waitTime: number,
openHour: string,
closeHour: string,
distance: string
```

That said, you could define a **type** for these restaurants instead of implicitly typing them, like:

```
export interface Restaurant {
  name: string;
  priceBracket: string;
  waitTime: number;
  openHour: string;
  closeHour: string;
  distance: string;
}
```

And then update your export to be:

```
const restaurants: Restaurant[] = [
  {
     ...
  },
  ...
]

export default restaurants;
```

Comment: Can you mention the fact that you can disable the noImplicitAny in tsconfig?

Comment: Hey Tom, thank you for your answer! I added the file that's being used for the import. I believe this would be an array that holds items? How would I specify that for i?

Comment: @juanvicareer check the updated answer. The tl;dr is you should define a type for the `restaurants` array and then use that type everywhere you're dealing with these objects