# error TS7006: Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having trouble determining the root of this error. Here is the full error code from the terminal:

```
Error: src/app/box/show-box/show-box.component.ts:33:13 - error TS7006: Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.

33   editClick(item){
```

Here is my corresponding show-box.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-box',
  templateUrl: './show-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-box.component.css']
})
export class ShowBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:SharedService) { }

  BoxList:any=[];

  ModalTitle:string;
  ActivateAddEditBoxComp:boolean=false;
  box:any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshBoxList();
  }

  addClick(){
    this.box={
      BoxId:0,
      BoxName1:"",
      BoxName2:"",
    }
    this.ModalTitle="Add Box";
    this.ActivateAddEditBoxComp=true;
  }

  editClick(item){
    this.box=item;
    this.ModalTitle="Edit Box";
    this.ActivateAddEditBoxComp=true;
  }

  closeClick(){
    this.ActivateAddEditBoxComp=false;
    this.refreshUserList();
  }

  refreshBoxList(){
    this.service.getBoxList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.BoxList=data;
    })
  }

}
```

Here is the relating show-component.box.html file

```
<table class="table table striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>BoxId</th>
      <th>Box 1</th>
      <th>Box 2</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dataItem of BoxList">
      <td>{{dataItem.BoxId}}</td>
      <td>{{dataItem.Box1}}</td>
      <td>{{dataItem.Box2}}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="ovwrflow:auto btn btn-primary mr-1" data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#exampleModal"
          (click)="editClick(dataItem)"
          data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
          >Add Box</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What would be the root of my problem? I have seen other proposed solutions where people set "strict":false, but this seems to only be a surface fix while still providing a runtime issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify type as `any` to argument `item` will solve your issue.

```
editClick(item: any) {
    this.box=item;
    this.ModalTitle="Edit Box";
    this.ActivateAddEditBoxComp=true;
}
```

Reference:
[Specifying Type Arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#specifying-type-arguments)