# Permutations using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, permutation

I wrote a function getMaxNumber that accepts a number, does all possible permutations of it's numbers and returns the biggest one.

For example, getMaxNmber(123) should return 321

Everything works fine except Typescript returns an error: **/getMaxNumber.ts(9,21): error TS7006: Parameter 'nums' implicitly has an 'any' type.**

Would appreciate any help!

Here's my code so far:

```
const getMaxNumber = (inputNum: number) : number => {
  let nums = inputNum.toString().split('')

   function permute(nums: Array<string>) : Array<Array<string>> {
    let result = [];

    if (nums.length === 0) return [];
    if (nums.length === 1) return [nums];

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      const currentNum = nums[i];
      const remainingNums = nums.slice(0, i).concat(nums.slice(i + 1));
      const remainingNumsPermuted = permute(remainingNums);

      for (let j = 0; j < remainingNumsPermuted.length; j++) {
        const permutedArray = [currentNum].concat(remainingNumsPermuted[j]);
        result.push(permutedArray);
      }
    }

    return result;
    }

    let permutations = permute(nums)

    return Math.max(...permutations.map(el => +el.join('')));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Comment: You defined `nums` as a variable in the `getMaxNumber` method and also as parameter inside the `permute` method. They are conflicting, you should rename one of them.

Comment: @JSONDerulo exactly! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please consider editing the title to this question so that it indicates what issue you are facing: you're not asking for someone to write an algorithm that does permutations or even calculates the max-number; you're asking for someone to clear up your typescript error.   If you were asking about the max-number algorithm, I'd suggest sorting and not permuting, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7gOEN).