# filter parameter requiring type in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I'm having some trouble trying to filter an array before assigning the data to my angular component, I have an array of hints but I only want to display 1 hint initially

my problem is that when I try to filter my array by a hint that matches the ID of 1 I keep getting

"'hint' implicitly has an 'any' type." in the cli but this should be fine as its just a counter

I have disabled string injection params in my tsconfig.json and followed various other posts about disabling strict typescript injection rules but I can't get angular to quit asking me for a type  for the counter, thus I cannot use the filter function here

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SpecsService } from 'src/app/specs.service';
import {Hint} from './hint';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hintbox',
  templateUrl: './hintbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hintbox.component.css']
})

export class HintboxComponent implements OnInit {
 currentHint: Hint[]=[]
 hint: Hint={hint:'',id:0}
 
  constructor(private specsService: SpecsService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.specsService.getHints().subscribe((response)=> this.currentHint= response.filter(hint:Hint => hint.id===1));   
  }

}
```

below is an image of my response object
[image: console log of my response object]

hoping for any advice, or if there is a more reasonable way to filter the data later that would be amazing

here is my specs service function, its pointed at my dummy json server

```
export class SpecsService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}


  getHints(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/Hints`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share `SpecsService` in particular the `getHints()` function

Comment: certainly, I've included it, I'm new to angular but i'm assuming everything in my service is correct as its at least pulling data itself from the json server with no issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getHints()` function returns an Observable of type `Object`. That is why whenever you try to assign it returns an unknown type. A simple solution to check that this is the case try below

```typescript
  getHints() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/Hints`)
  }
```

With the above, the error will go away but this may not be the best course of action.

So to solve your problem in a better way would be to understand the expected object and type your response

From your code it looks like you are receiving back an array of items so you can have something like below

```typescript
interface IHintResponse {
  id:  number;
  // Other props here
}

  getHints() {
    return this.http.get<IHintResponse[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/Hints`)
  }
```

Comment: ah I see, thanks for your help, this fixed the issue with calling filter in terms of the type throwing the error, but my primary issue remains.... even when I try to declare a type for 'hint' as a param in my filter() I get:  'hint' implicitly has type 'any' (this is my original question btw)

Comment: I was able to find a workaround to fix my issue where I can't declare a type for a parameter -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type   although to follow up, technically via typescript the above answer should work per that question as well ^ I just personally wasn't able to get the error to go away from exporting a custom interface :) so thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of confusing to wrap my head around your code.  I don't use `JSON.stringify()` in my code ever--Angular `HTTPClientModule` will already convert the results to JSON.

But, generically, create a class for the type:

```
export class Hint {
   id: number,
   otherprop: string
}
```

Your conversion code can strongly type:

```
this.specsService.getHints().subscribe((response)=> this.currentHint= response.filter(hint: Hint => hint.id===1));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, have corrected the code, but since my response is in json object format, filter will not execute on it ```Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'``` not sure how to convert response to an array mid assignment, I thought it already was an array, I have edited my code above to include the response, as a side note, using my original code which parses the json back into object format after stringifying it, filter doesn't throw this error

Comment: As far as I now, the filter only works on an array, which is why you'd be getting that error.  I don't know enough about your code or data structures to be able to offer further clarification.