# I am not able to read the image. It's showing the following error

Tags: node.js, angular

This is my ng code:

```html
<div class="p-field col-12">
   <label for="image">Main Image</label>
     <input type="file" class="p-inputtext" accept="image/*" (change)="onImageUpload($event)">
     <div>
       <img {src}="imageDisplay" alt="">
     </div>
</div>
```

This is my component code:

```js
export class ProductsFormComponent implements OnInit {
     
  imageDisplay: string | ArrayBuffer | null | undefined;
       
  constructor() { }
    
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onImageUpload(event){
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    if (file) {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      
      fileReader.onload = () => {
            this.imageDisplay = fileReader.result;
      }

      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }    
  }

  get productForm(){
    return this.form.controls;
  }
}
```

This is the Error:

```
Error: apps/admin/src/app/pages/products/products-form/products-form.component.ts:77:17 - error TS7006: Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.

77   onImageUpload(event)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the way you defined the `onImageLoad` method.

```
onImageUpload(event)
```

This is because of typescript.

1. As angular uses typescript we can specify the type of arguments to method calls.
   Example: the following will resolve the error

```
onImageUpload(event: Event)
```

2. There is a `tsconfig.json` file autogenerated by angular cli. This file specifies the config for the typescript compiler to use while compiling your code. Here we can     configure the typing we require in the project etc. So setting `noImplicitAny` option to false will solve the issue too.

I would recommend to go with option1 if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. And I solved my problem also. Thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
const file: File = <File>event.target.files[0];
```

instead of

```
this.file = event.target.files[0];
```

and then

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

try this it will work