# How to convert Expressjs Arrow Function from JavaScript to TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am converting a Expressjs project from JavaScript to TypeScript.

The initial JavaScript module ***catchAsyncError.js***:

```
module.exports = theFunc => (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(theFunc(req, res, next)).catch(next);
}
```

I tried converting to TypeScript ***catchAsyncError.ts***:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction} from "express";

const theFunc => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    Promise.resolve(theFunc(req, res, next)).catch(next);
}
export default theFunc;
```

But there is an **Error: Variable 'theFunc' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7005)**

Can someone please advise and explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Hi Dan P, i have edited my post. The error is included

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type see if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the link given by cmgchess,
[Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

I managed to covert it:

***catchAsyncError.ts***

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction} from "express";


const catchAsyncError = (theFunc: any) => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    Promise.resolve(theFunc(req, res, next)).catch(next);
}

export default catchAsyncError;
```

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to swap a `=>` to a `=` in your function definition:

```
//   see here \/
const theFunc = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    Promise.resolve(theFunc(req, res, next)).catch(next);
}
```

Comment: Dan P also added return type (:Promise).  May be should be Promise<void> because it could be implicit Promise<any> ?

Comment: I didn't mean to add Promise there, my fault! Function doesn't need a return value.

Comment: Hi Dan P, your code doesn't give error but it seems the meaning is changed