# How can I declare an array outside a function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, function

I am creating an array of items with my drag and drop function:

```
drag.ondrop = (event: DragEvent) => {

   const items = [];

   while (length--) {
      items.push(event.dataTransfer.files[i].path);
      i++
    }

   console.log(items); 

}
```

But now everytime I drop a new element a new array is created. But I need the new item added to the array that already exists.

To achieve this I try to declare the array outside the function like this:

```
const items = [];

    drag.ondrop = (event: DragEvent) => {
    
       
    
       while (length--) {
          items.push(event.dataTransfer.files[i].path);
          i++
        }
    
    
    }

console.log(items);
```

But I get an error:

> TS7005: Variable 'items' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Comment: @Liam Isn't there a better duplicate? The accepted and upvoted answer suggests `user: any`. Other answers suggests `"noImplicitAny": false` and/or `strict: false`. That's really bad. It's like saying: "Disable TypeScript checks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a type:

```
const items: string[] = [];

drag.ondrop = (event: DragEvent) => {  
  while (length--) {
    items.push(event.dataTransfer.files[i].path);
    i++
  }
}

console.log(items);
```