# Mapping inside of map with interfaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to map an array inside another map with an array. These are the interfaces:

```
interface Props {
  columns: Array<{field: string, headerName: string, width: number}>;
  rows: Array<{id: string, order: number, name: string, timeRequired: number}>;
  handleSortOrder: (id: string, order: number, type: string) => void;
  path: string;
  updateSortOrder: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>; 
  loading: boolean;
}
```

The types that are used are columns and rows. This is a part of the mapping:

```
{
  rows.map((r) => (
    <tr className='micro-course-resource-table-row'>
      {columns.map((c) => (
        <td className='micro-course-td'>
          <div
            role='button'
            tabIndex={-1}
            onKeyDown={() => navigate(`/${path}/${r.id}`)}
            onClick={() => navigate(`/${path}/${r.id}`)}
          >
            {r[c.field]}
          </div>
        </td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  ));
}
```

The error I'm getting is in the div: {r[c.field]} which states that "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ id: string; order: number; name: string; timeRequired: number; }'."

Does anyone know the answer? I've tried to implement "...as keyof MyClass" but the error is not disappearing. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, *as plain text in the body of your post*. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values. (If you want to provide a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NnKYem) that's great, but please also put the full example *in the body of the post as text*.)

Comment: Presumably something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk0eDw) is what you want, where you give the `field` property of `columns` a stronger type corresponding to the keys of the `rows` property elements.  Does that suffice?  If so, note how I removed all the other stuff to make a [mre]... if you do that in your question too I could write up an answer.  If not, please [edit] your code to make a [mre] that demonstrates why it doesn't work for you.  And good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are using `noImplicitAny: true`, and currently TypeScript doesn't know that `column.field` is in fact a valid property inside rows. Try `r:any` like below, or disable the rule by setting  `"noImplicitAny": false` in your `tsconfig.json` file

```ts
rows.map((r:any) => ((
```

Maybe this answer is what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43070857/1471485

EDIT:
Doing what @jcalz mentioned in the comment of your question is probably the way to go.