# How can I find an array by object value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

This is my variable `tree`:

[image]

I want to find the element by it path. (in the case `Documents it is 0)

Like this `myFolder` gives me the correct output:

```
var myFolder = tree.childs[0]
```

But I do not have the key, I have only the path. I tried:

```
var myFolder = tree.map(Folder => Folder.path).indexOf('Documents/');
```

But I get an error message (implicity has an 'any' type)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: @Ivar Thank you. I tried this `var obj = _.find(tree, function (obj) { return obj.path == 'Documents/' })` but still error

Comment: @Ivar I also tried `var item = tree.find(item => item.path === 'Documents/')` still error

Comment: can you provide some example data of your tree in code? (not the screenshot)

Comment: See [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Comment: It works now: var item = tree.childs.find(item => item.path === 'Documents/')

Comment: does this mean your tree is never more than one level deep?

Comment: Please edit your question to include textual input, rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mainFolder = {
    childs: [
        { path: 'ExamplePathNameOne' },
        { path: 'ExamplePathNameTwo' },
        { path: 'ExamplePathNameThree' },
    ]
}

const folder = mainFolder.childs.find(c => c.path === 'ExamplePathNameOne');
```

---

But to fix your error message, either set `"noImplicitAny": false` in your `tsconfig.json` file **or** define an interface for the objects you are using, f.e. `MainFolder` and `Folder`.

```
interface MainFolder {
    childs: Folder[];
}

interface Folder {
    path: string;
}

const mainFolder: MainFolder = {
    childs: [
        { path: 'ExamplePathNameOne' },
        { path: 'ExamplePathNameTwo' },
        { path: 'ExamplePathNameThree' },
    ]
}

const folder = mainFolder.childs.find(c => c.path === 'ExamplePathNameOne');
```