# How to type a JavaScript function with JSDoc + TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc, tsc, tsserver

I'm trying to use `tsc` with plain, Vanilla JS and I'm stumped on how to declare the type a function.

It seems like it should be this simple:

```js
/** @type PersonGreet */
person.greet = function greet(other) {
  return `Hello ${other.name}, my name is ${person.name}!`;
};
```

## Reduced Test Case

Ignore the fact that someone may want to refactor this into using classes or prototypes or some such - it serves well as a demonstration of the problem.

Repo: https://github.com/BeyondCodeBootcamp/hello-tsc

```js
"use strict";

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Person
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {PersonGreet} greet
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Function} PersonGreet
 * @param {Person} other
 * @returns {String}
 */

let Person = {};

/**
 * Creates a person
 * @param {Object} p
 * @param {String} p.name
 * @returns {Person}
 */
Person.create = function (p) {
  let person = {};

  person.name = p.name;

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // error TS7006: Parameter 'other' implicitly has an 'any' type.  <======= WRONG!
  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /** @type PersonGreet */
  person.greet = function greet(other) {
    return `Hello ${other.name}, my name is ${person.name}!`;
  };

  return person;
};

module.exports = Person;
```

## Incorrectly Typed as "any"

When I run `tsc` to check it gives an error about an implicit any:

```bash
tsc -p jsconfig.json
```

```
person.js:28:33 - error TS7006: Parameter 'other' implicitly has an 'any' type.

28   person.greet = function greet(other) {
                                   ~~~~~


Found 1 error in person.js:28
```

## What to do?

To me this seems like a bug in `tsc`... but this is JS 101 stuff, surely there must be a way to type a function?

What annotation do I need to use to declare the function's type? Or can `tsc` / `tsserver` / `typescript` just not handle this kind of rudimentary use of JS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Comment: I found a workaround: `@typedef {(other: Person) => string} PersonGreet` instead of just defining it as "Function"

Comment: @EvanM no. That's unrelated. This is about a declared type being misinterpreted as not declared due to being a function.

Comment: Best workaround `@callback` instead of `@typedef {Function}`. I've filed a bug with tsc: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50274

Comment: It feels like the underlying issue here was that `Person` should be a class with a .create` function that has accurate docs on it, using a normal `new Person(name)` instead of a faux static Person.create? No need for all those separate "unconnected" pieces of JSDoc that way. (Even if you _also_ add a `static create` to the class, yielding a new Person instance).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Classes were added by a Microsoft-led committee decision as part of bringing C# to the browser. I just want plain-old JS, not fraken-C#. The beauty of JS to me is how simple it can be - you don't need anything more than a few keywords, Objects, & Functions.

Comment: No they weren't, and classes make JS code quite a lot more beautiful and a joy to work with compared to manually building a prototype chain and calling bind, call, and apply all over the place. By all means, don't use classes, that's your choice, but don't make up nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1

You should use [`@callback`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-callback.html) instead of [`@function`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-function.html) like so:

```js
"use strict";

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Person
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {PersonGreet} greet
 */

/**
 * @callback PersonGreet
 * @param {Person} other
 * @returns {String}
 */

let Person = {};

/**
 * Creates a person
 * @param {Object} p
 * @param {String} p.name
 * @returns {Person}
 */
Person.create = function (p) {
  let person = {};

  person.name = p.name;

  /** @type {PersonGreet} */
  person.greet = function greet(other) {
    return `Hello ${other.name}, my name is ${person.name}!`;
  };

  return person;
};

module.exports = Person;
```

### Solution 2

Or, declare a [`@typedef`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) using typescript syntax like the following:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {(other: Person) => string} PersonGreet
 */
```

Comment: Side note: It seems that `tsc` doesn't recognize `@function` in any capacity, at all.