# Typescript function overload implicitly has any type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
type UpdateConsumerT = {
  obj: {
    min_quantity: number
    fixed_price: number
    date_start: string | boolean
    date_end: string | boolean
  }
}

type UpdateProducerT = {
  obj: {
    min_qty: number
    price: number
    date_start: string | boolean
    date_end: string | boolean
  }
}

export async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id: number,
  obj: UpdateConsumerT,
  isProduction: false
): Promise<number>
export async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id: number,
  obj: UpdateProducerT,
  isProduction: true
): Promise<number>
export async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id,
  obj,
  isProduction = false
) { ... }
```

I have this function, and i try to use overloads

But for some reason it says

> Parameter 'pricelist_item_id' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

[image]

My question is, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to explicitly specify the parameter types and return type on the implementation:

```
type UpdateConsumerT = {
  obj: {
    min_quantity: number
    fixed_price: number
    date_start: string | boolean
    date_end: string | boolean
  }
}

type UpdateProducerT = {
  obj: {
    min_qty: number
    price: number
    date_start: string | boolean
    date_end: string | boolean
  }
}

async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id: number,
  obj: UpdateConsumerT,
  isProduction: false
): Promise<number>
async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id: number,
  obj: UpdateProducerT,
  isProduction: true
): Promise<number>
async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id: number,
  obj: UpdateProducerT | UpdateConsumerT,
  isProduction = false
): Promise<number> { return new Promise(() => {}) }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAmBDYEDCB7AdgZwK4FsIAnAFSgF4oBvAWACgop0AjAKwC5r7HH8BLTAH0AjrkSZgfUJ0wFmxbjwBmfAB4R4gsET4BjCDLkKGPJCkHZgiIsE6WdmAOZQAPlGbp0AGwjjFjMwhBCEx4O2AHZzcPb19MRQBfeiS6elBIWARkCAAFInR4XH1SCi4TFg4ynih+IWFpKFl8eSJ-KG09A0ajVpMA7IsrG3DI13dPHz8+qEDg0JGBKPHYqcYUlPpEbBBMXSglXF3JLChcLJQ8zq8+SwBJFHwACkUO-WvLQSkIfE+w7ubiAAaRQVThwQIYHAEYgkYEmG55ApFY6YThKRBebAQegASk4iP4WIAPE0WgA+TbbXb7Q66FGnc65HRvG7Ae7fZ4mV4Qd7AT4PX6GAFEOGMUGZQKIwrFWGKBH5aUozgRXDYuh4qAEm4QEk9Cl0LY7PYHI58E5nSXMnms9lPF5W3n876C-4tUVMNhgxlSoowsbg7KQvCEUju+VIulmzCldGYtUarXE0nEMnUKBECDAXBEaOYCAAd01+UJEEejxxFFTVASFYSQA)

Answer (score 0):

[Overload function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) implementations do not currently have their parameter types inferred [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) from the call signatures.  There's a longstanding open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#25352](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25352), but for now it's not part of the language.

Until and unless that gets implemented, you will need to manually [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) the function implementation's parameters:

```
export async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id: number,
  obj: UpdateConsumerT,
  isProduction: false
): Promise<number>
export async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id: number,
  obj: UpdateProducerT,
  isProduction: true
): Promise<number>

export async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id: number, // <-- annotate
  obj: UpdateConsumerT | UpdateProducerT, // <-- annotate
  isProduction = false // this is inferred as boolean from false
) {
  return null!; // suppress errors
}
```

---

Do note that because your call signatures return the same type for each call, you don't need to use overloads.  Instead you can use a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types):

```
export async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id: number,
  ...[obj, isProduction]:
    [obj: UpdateConsumerT, isProduction: false] |
    [obj: UpdateProducerT, isProduction: true]
): Promise<number> {
  return null!; // suppress errors
}

declare const consumer: UpdateConsumerT;
declare const producer: UpdateProducerT;
updatePricelistItem(123, consumer, false); // okay
updatePricelistItem(123, producer, true); // okay
updatePricelistItem(123, consumer, true); // error
```

This approach is even better for your implementation because that rest parameter is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) with `isProduction` as the discriminant, so you can [use control flow analysis on the destructured parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions) to narrow `obj` based on `isProduction`:

```
export async function updatePricelistItem(
  pricelist_item_id: number,
  ...[obj, isProduction]:
    [obj: UpdateConsumerT, isProduction: false] |
    [obj: UpdateProducerT, isProduction: true]
): Promise<number> {
  if (isProduction) {
    obj.obj.price // okay, known to be UpdateProducerT
  } else {
    obj.obj.fixed_price // okay, known to be UpdateConsumerT
  }
  return null!;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAmBDYEDCB7AdgZwK4FsIAnAFSgF4oBvAWACgop0AjAKwC5r7HH8BLTAH0AjrkSZgfUJ0wFmxbjwBmfAB4R4gsET4BjCDLkKGPJCkHZgiIsE6WdmAOZQAPlGbp0AGwjjFjMwhBCEx4O2AHZzcPb19MRQBfeiS6elBIWARkCAAFInR4XH1SCi4TFg4ynih+IWFpKFl8eSJ-KG09A0ajVpMA7IsrG3DI13dPHz8+qEDg0JGBKPHYqcYUlPoIVTB0GyhEbBBMXSglXGPJLChcLJQ8zq8+SwBJFHwACkUO-UfLQSkIPh-mFus1iAAaRQVThwQIYHAEYgkSEmJ55ApFS6YThKRBebAQegASk46P4BIAPE0WgA+TbbXbAfaHY6nc66LHXW65HQ-J7AV6Az4mb4QX7Af5vYGGMFEFGMaGZQLowrFZGKNH5VVYzgRXCEugkqBkp4QKk9Ol0LY7PYHI4nM4XPhXG7K3li-mCj5fd3iyWA6WglryphsGHc+F4QglNyw7IqopIkOajEc52YUq4-EGolVKBECDAXBEDOyLxeACEAG5kvR4BBdF5rNBdFhLFBWwjo+G4W3EaQa3R643mx220ztKniD341rEwP6K7Zw9PW93gBGABMAGZwWOuxDTniCUSq1AAPTnpgAa0QIEX3PufJea63u-ac+Ke71EFPF6v6C3vedBLncvqrkKb57p2UaHj+f6XlAxD5L09CYIghDYGAiD6FAABChYoEQebWoyzL2myTouo+4EvkKbSin6AJAnwILUhCbQAHTcQA2hUe4ptq6YALrsG0jB8WGSrZJG-bIlAgmYumOLHhAwmuOJUCSZUcZgVOpACdgCZplgupEPqwmKEaJqUuxRA0nmjB8EoUDvIpJmYLmtDTAqbCcRUnGiv+N53m0CRIdmjk8AFAUqOomhBYhgGhdMKTVAWRYlt05bVok9CKMOTYFvu7Ywf2M4oLJ0YkIOAQNkVLbjh++kVTy+k1YooE8iudEfFBJX9nuWYnmeSVAZ1NE9QKr47nuk6qnB5m-qNAHjSYXVPh6vUbrNA3Rt+S0IVeyG7PldAJEAA)